# Polygon Volume (ArcMap 10.7) calculates a volume of zero?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, 3d-analyst, tin

I'm calculating partial TIN volumes using `Polygon Volume` in ArcMap 10.7. I've done this hundreds of times using `arcpy` and for the most part, it works fine (Height Field = *MAX*; Reference Plane = *BELOW*). However, sometimes the routine calculates a volume and a surface area of **zero**, respectively, without any error messages.
My data can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT?usp=sharing). I have provided one example of a TIN and a shapefile that works, and one example of a combination that doesn't. I cannot figure out the difference between the two.

EDIT:
Following @Vince, I've used `Check Geometry` on the shapefile (as it does not work with TINs), which gave me the error notification:
`Could not find spatial index`.
When `Repair Geometry` did nothing to fix this, I simply ran `Add spatial index`.
After that, the `Check Geometry` routine gave me no further errors - however, I still get an area and volume of zero when I use `Polygon Volume`.

When I use other shapefiles (that overlap with the TIN to a larger or smaller extent) the volume/area calculation runs fine. So, I suspect the error has to lie within the shapefile - but I have no idea what caused it.

Comment: Try running Check Geometry and/or Repair Geometry to identify and correct topology errors. A "bowtie" (quadrilateral with 2nd and 3rd vertices swapped) will usually show zero area.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info! Check geometry did indeed show some errors, but my problem is not solved. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @FlorianMlehliv, which column did you use as height? Your TIN has heights ranging from 2400-2250, but all the values from the table your are much lower. I did a test run, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @alecsx: Thanks for the test run! I use the "MAX" column as height. But the height values for the shapefile ("MIN" and "MAX") are approximately in the same range as the TIN (2463-2243), so there should be no problem. Which column did you take when you succeeded with the test run?

Comment: I used one of your  hazard columns, and now I tried it with the MAX and it also works, just set your reference plane to BELOW, because if you set it ABOWE, you will get 0 values.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/polygon-volume.htm

Comment: Good morning, @alecsx! I have used the BELOW reference plane, but it still did not work for me. But if it worked for you with both data sets I provided, the error seems to be on my side. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find the reason for this not working for me but for others, however, this alternative should work:

Generate a copy of the TIN, edit this TIN with the polygon and then use `Polygon Volume` or `Surface Volume`.